# Java memory clean

Tags: java, memory

Hello Please help here in this issue:

called class

```
CreateHtml CreateHtml = new CreateHtml ();
String GetHtml = CreateHtml.main ();
System.out.println (GetHtml;
CreateHtml = null;
GetHtml = null;
System.gc ();
```

That is, the class generates html code, prints it and then destroy. As far as I understand, with the memory must be cleared? Memory in the peak load of the operation up to 300 mb (convert images in base64) and remains so to continue, CreateHtml = null; GetHtml = null; System.gc (); not not affect anything. Tell me, what am I doing wrong? How to properly clear the memory in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't.  The JVM will clear it when it needs to.

Comment: What all you need is to configure the JVM parameters correctly, then the JVM will take care of the cleaning up process.

Comment: add sleep(N) after `System.gc();`  if you wanna **just check** memory usage in code.

Comment: How I can configure the JVM?

Comment: @user1786639 "how can I configure the JVM" - type that literally into google, see what you get.